# Java 8 stream api control output

Tags: java, java-8, html-parsing, jsoup, java-stream

I have the following code.

```
List<String> parseAttribValueByTag(String tag, String attrib, List<String> attribName) throws IOException {

    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements inputs = doc.select(tag + "[" + attrib + "]");
    for (String item : attribName) {
        System.out.println(inputs.stream()
            .filter(input -> input.attr("name").contains("__VIEWSTATE"))
            .findFirst());
    }
return keys;
}
```

It gives me the following output

`Optional[<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="5ue/NxnSLQ2akzQo5R8wBEZ,,."`

I would like to control the output so it only gives me `__VIEWSTATE "5ue/NxnSLQ2akzQo5R8wBEZ,,."`

I've tried using `.map(input -> input.attr("value"))` and it gives me `Optional[5ue/NxnSLQ2akzQo5R8wBEZ,,.`

but when I add an additional `.map(input -> input.attr("name"))` to also give me the name I get the following error "**Cannot resolve method 'attr(java.lang.String)'** ". What is it I'm doing wrong in the code? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `.map(input -> input.attr("value"))`, you convert your `Stream` to a `Stream<String>` (assuming that `attr` returns a `String`), and `String` doesn't have an `attr` method, so the second `map` call doesn't pass compilation (hence the compilation error - `Cannot resolve method 'attr(java.lang.String)'`).

You could use a single `map` operation to obtain both attributes. For example :

```
    System.out.println(inputs.stream()
        .filter(input -> input.attr("name").contains("__VIEWSTATE"))
        .map(input -> input.attr("name") + " " + input.attr("value"))
        .findFirst());
```

Comment: Thanks @Eran. That works. The output I now get is `Optional[__VIEWSTATE fmxGAU4TK1P1`. Is there a way of getting rid of of the `Optional[` in the output?

Comment: @user148095: Instead of `System.out.println( … .findFirst())` use `… .findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println)` to print the contents of the `Optional`, in case there is one. Or use `System.out.println( … .findFirst().orElse("alternative"))` to print either, the contents or an alternative if there was no match.